# Integrand with branch point

Tags: complex-analysis, branch-cuts, branch-points

I am trying to learn how to work with branch points. I decided to change the sign in the next classical example:
$$f(x)=\int_{-1}^{+1} \frac{1}{\sqrt{1-x^2}}$$
  In this example, simply select the path of integration by drawing a cut along the active axis from -1 to +1. Answer is known - it's $\pi$. I changed the sign of the radical expression, and now I'm trying to solve an integral of the next form:
$$f(x)=\int_{-1}^{+1} \frac{1}{\sqrt{1+x^2}}$$

And here I ran into difficulties - I don’t know which path of integration I should choose, since the branch points are on the imaginary axis, and I need to reduce the integral along the closed path to the integral along the real axis from -1 to 1.

If we do by analogy with the original number, then I come to the fact that the integral now varies from -i to i and does not reduce to the integral of a real variable.

Could you please explain which contour should be chosen?

Comment: Shouldn't you be integrating between $\pm i$?

Comment: If you mean that I have to integrate along the banks of the cut between ±i, then yes - I do. But with this integration, we cannot return to the original integral of the real variable, which is equal to the residue at infinity